# grub and grub2 seems to run sequentially at boot time

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, clonezilla

Recently I have cloned my Ubuntu installation from one drive to another using clonezilla, parted magic. It seems that the clonezilla has put its own bootloader into the target drive.

Before cloning, My computer would boot really quick into Ubuntu without any grub or grub2 splash screens.

Now when I boot, first I get a blak splash screen:

[image: grub black splash screen]

Then, immediately it goes into the normal purple grub2 splash screen:

[image: grub 2 splash screen]

My inital guess is that somehow I ended up having both grub and grub2 bootloader! I would like to know how can I get rid of the first one, because I use the second one now to also choose to boot in windows sometimes.

Also what can I do about that error message of grub? I hope I can get rid of the first one because it delays my boot time for about 5 seconds.

Here is my "fdisk -l" result if usefull!

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 8052 MB, 8052015104 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 978 cylinders, total 15726592 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4f20b187

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *        2048    15726591     7862272    b  W95 FAT32

Disk /dev/sda: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29185 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00076d7a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   458702847   229350400   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       458702848   468860927     5079040   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5a82a995

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048     1026047      512000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2         1026048   234438655   116706304    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall the GRUB boot loader to the disk.
The Master Boot Record gets overwritten.

Even if it can be done from the running OS,
I recommend to do it from the Live media.

First unplug the `/dev/mmcblk0` device.

Boot from Ubuntu installation media.
Select 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.

On the Live desktop open a terminal.
Execute the following commands :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt  
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Note : `sda` = disk | `sda1` = system partition

Answer (score 3):

### Method A

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but you may give it what it wants. First of all, see what locale files you have on your system:

```
cd /
locate grub.mo
```

My output looks like this:

```
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_CA/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo
/usr/share/locale-langpack/ro/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo
```

Basically, get one of these files (the one you're interested in), compress it to `gz` and copy it to `boot` folder of GRUB.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo /boot/grub/locale/en.mo
```

Now, according to [this claim](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=817187#c5), GRUB looks first for `mo` files and if there is none, looks for gzipped one. So it should be enough to fix your problem. Yet to be completely sure, do:

```
gzip /boot/grub/locale/en.mo
```

And definitely you don't have both Grub and Grub2 installed. That is just an error message telling you that Grub is missing a localization file.

### Method B

Try reinstalling Grub from the running operating system. There is no need for booting a live medium.

```
sudo apt-get install grub-pc-bin
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

This will work for a default Grub MBR installation only!

Comment: I dont have any such file on my Ubuntu : 

`severus@tux:/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES$ ls -l
total 112
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 108974 Aug  3  2015 iso_3166_2.mo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    516 Feb 12 00:27 update-notifier.mo`

Comment: :( I am not finding it any where, the output of `cd /usr/share/locale ; ls -lar | grep grub.mo` is nothing :(